# Slow top_hits aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I have a very basic top_hits aggregation, but it performs poorly if there are too many hits in the result set (an additional second or so compared to a search that returns a flat set of hits with around a million hits). Here is the query.

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "hits": {
      "aggs": {
        "children": {
          "top_hits": {
            "_source": "preview",
            "size": 3
          }
        },
        "top_score": {
          "max": {
            "script": "_score"
          }
        }
      },
      "terms": {
        "field": "rollupId",
        "size": 10,
        "order": {
          "top_score": "desc"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "states",
      "fields": [
        "title^3",
        "nameText^2.5",
        "placeText^2",
        "allText"
      ],
      "type": "cross_fields",
      "operator": "and"
    }
  },
  "from": 0,
  "size": 0
}
```

I'm only wanting 10 results, each with only 3 hits within it. Why is this so slow?

Comment: Hi Robert, I am facing a similar situation here. were you able to find a solution to this?